# Terms in a generated substructure

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\underline{B}$ be a $\tau$-structure and $G\subseteq B$. Suppose $\underline{A}=\langle G\rangle_B$ denote the smallest substructure of $\underline{B}$ generated by $G$.

> Show that for each $a\in A$, there exist a $\tau$-term $t(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $g_1,\ldots,g_n\in G$ such that $t^{\underline{B}}(g_1,\ldots,g_n)=a$.

**My attempt**: Let $$C=\{a\in A\mid \exists \tau\text{-term }t(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \text{ and } g_1,\ldots,g_n\in G :t^{\underline{B}}(g_1,\ldots,g_n)=a \}.$$
My idea is to show that $\underline{C}$ is a substructure of $B$ and $G\subseteq C$. Then I can directly obtain $\underline{A}\subseteq\underline{C}$.

To show that $G\subseteq C$, let $g\in G$ and for a variable $x_1$, let $t=x_1$, then $t^{\underline{B}}(g)=g$ and hence $g\in C$.

> Is this correct? Moreover, how do I show that $\underline{C}$ is a substructure?

Comment: It's correct. What does it mean to be a substructure? Check that $C$ is closed under the basic operations. It's quite straightforward.

Comment: @Berci I'm not able to show that $C$ is closed under relations.

Comment: Every subset is closed under relations. Or, what do you mean?

Comment: @Berci $\underline{A}$ is called a substructure of $\underline{B}$ (with same signature $\tau$) if $A\subseteq B$, for each $R\in\tau$, we have $\overline{a}\in R^{\underline{A}}$ iff $\overline{a}\in R^{\underline{B}}$, and for each $f\in\tau$, we have $f^{\underline{A}}(\overline{A})=f^{\underline{B}}(\overline{A})$.

Comment: Yes, correct. The relations are preserved in  any subset! (Because their interpretation is simply kept the same in the substructure.) So you only need to worry about closedness under basic operations and your solution is complete.

Comment: @Berci Then why does relation preserving need to be mentioned in the definition?

Comment: It's to clarify the term 'substructure' (in current text, at least). One might call $A$ a substructure of $B$ if (it's still closed under operations) and whenever $R^A(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ for some elements $a_i\in A$ and relation symbol $R$, we have $R^B(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$, but the converse is not required, so one might choose a smaller interpretation of $R$ in the subset $A$, and this possibility here is excluded.

Comment: @Berci Why is that possibility here excluded? I really don't see why $\underline{C}$ is a substructure.

Comment: I don't see your problem. In some other texts 'substructure' is used in the other sense. But don't get confused about it. How would you interpret the relation symbols on $\underline C$? There's a straightforward way to do that which is also unique if we want $\underline C$ to be a substructure in your sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is fine.
$\def\B{\underline B} \def\C{\underline C}$

For any $n$-ary basic operation symbol $f$ and elements $a_i={t_i}^{\B}(\vec{b_i}) \ \in C$ with all $b_{i,j}\in G$, just consider the composed term $\tau:=f\big(t_1(\vec{x_1}),\,\dots,\,t_n(\vec{x_n})\big)$, so that
$$f^\B(a_1,\dots,a_n)\ =\ f^\B\Big({t_1}^\B(\vec{b_1}),\,\dots,\,{t_n}^\B(\vec{b_n})\Big)\ =\  \tau^\B(\vec{b_1},\dots,\vec{b_n})\ \in C$$
so $C$ is closed under the interpretation $f^\B$ of $f$ within $\B$.

This is necessary for enabling us to define the interpretation $f^\C$ so that it is the restriction of $f^\B$, because operation symbols must be interpreted as functions defined on every $n$-tuples.

On the other hand, for an $n$-ary relation symbol $R$, we can (and actually must) simply define $R^\C(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ to have the same truth value as $R^\B(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ for any elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in C$.
This way the structure $\C$ defined on set $C$ (with the help of structure $\B$) is indeed a substructure.

---

Note that if the signature doesn't contain operation symbols, then *every subset* of any structure is a substructure (of course if we interpret each relation symbols as the restriction of those in the original structure).

Comment: Thank you! I see it now and I understand now that the reason to include relations in the definition of the substructure is to make it explicit that we consider restriction of relation.